# Context has null properties when entities in another project

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, t4

I'm using EF, and I generated two tt files. I left the context.tt in the ServerComponents project. I moved the entities .tt file to a Common project, to be shared by all projects in the solution. The problem is that all of the properties/entities within the context object are null at runtime, and I can't figure out why. It's like my context.tt doesn't know where the new entities are, but I don't know how to fix that. Does anyone know what I'm missing?

**Here is the server project:**

[image]

**Here is the common project:**

[image]

**And this is the state of context at runtime:**

[image]

I've tried too many things to list here. I'm hoping someone just knows this answer...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I got it. Through trial and error, making the CustodianEntities properties public worked (they were internal). This is in DataCustodianContext.context.cs. Now I just need to alter the tt file to make sure it keeps these public when generated again.

I considered deleting this question, but I'm hoping maybe this helps someone else.

[image]